# Use Session or CustomCatch?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, session

everyone. I am currently working in a .net mvc3 project team. Today ,my team leader told me to use a custom catch (implemented by him) instead of session .I saw the usage of both  are nearly the same. ( I can't see his source code :)

```
Session["somekey"] = somevalue, somevar = Session["somekey"]
```

&

```
CustomCatch["somekey"] = somevalue, somevar = CustomCatch["somekey"].
```

I want to ask what's the advantage my team leader want me to use his custom catch instead of session? Or he just want me to do the "extra" work?

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow ,can anybody tell me why I start my question as "hello ,everyone" ,but after I posted it ,the word "hello"is missing ,and the result is "everyone. I am ...." I respect everyone :)

Comment: without knowing what the CustomCatch does no answer can be provided. It could even simply be a Wrapper of the Session with some extra logging to what is added or accessed... ask him not us! :)

Comment: oh well, maybe is CustomCatch tests for nulls. However I would use MemoryCache in place of sessions.

Comment: @NextStep The Hello/thanks are frowned by the big bosses. They want your request to be terse and clear. We are all very polite here, so we know that in your mind you are thanking us :-)

Comment: @NextStep - they actually remove those greeting words automatically on posting a question - you can see more info and reasoning here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to say the truth. I consider the `Session` object to be one of the big evils (with `double`/`float`, `Regex`es that don't consider internationalization and diacritics (àèéìòù for example), `Regex`es in general, blocks of code that don't consider internationalization (àèéìòù, date and numeric formats) and some other ones).

You can use it to store the profile of the current user. You can user it to store the settings of the current user. Full stop. Everything else is bad bad bad.

This is because if your user does ctrl-n on a page, the new window that opens uses the same `Session`. Now begin thinking what could happen.

Perhaps what your Team Leader did solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what is `CustomCatch`. But if you want to make things simpler and more testable, create an interface `IStorageService` and its implementation using `Session` and the so-called `CustomCatch`. The storage service will be replace the calls in your example.

```
public interface IStorageService 
{ 
  void SetValue(string key, object value);
  object GetValue(string key);
}
```

For `Session`

```
public class SessionStorageService :  IStorageService 
{ 
  public void SetValue(string key, object value) 
  {
    HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = value; 
  }

  public object GetValue(string key) 
  {
    return HttpContext.Current.Session[key]; 
  }

}
```

The use of `Session` or `CustomCatch` will be limited to those implementations only and will not leak in other code.